# Simple variable reference

Tags: java, enums, java.util.scanner

So I'm currently trying make a simple rpg game, it's my first time so I'm learning haha, but my question is that, I am trying to reference a variable in another class I have for the player's choice of their class. P.S. I couldn't figure out what to look up so I'm sorry if this is a repeat question.

this is the main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inputRace =  new Scanner(System.in);
    player player1 = new player(race.valueOf(inputRace), profession.ranger);
}
```

and here is the `race` class I'm trying to reference

```
public enum race {
    orc, elf, human, dwarf
}
```

So all I'm trying to do is be able to take the user's input and do like race.("whatever their choice is"), but I haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks for any help and sorry if it's confusing.

Comment: `String raceString = inputRace.nextLine();` and then change race.valueOf(inputRace) to race.valueOf(raceString)

Comment: Seriously: there zillions of questions and tutorials that explain how to use scanners and enums.

Comment: thanks ishnark! and ghostcat, i was trying to find it haha.... i was mainly having problems using the variable for the race class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In other to access input data you must use scanner methods like next, nextInt, nextDouble etc.
In your case you are looking for string so it should look like this:

```
try {
    Race race = Race.valueOf( inputRace.next() ); // next returns string
    Player player1 = new Player(race, profession.ranger);
} catch ( IllegalArgumentException ex ) {
    System.err.println( "That race doesn't exsist" );
}
```

Note that I used upper case for Race and Player, this is standard way of naming your classes.

Also you should put your code in some kind of loop until he doesn't write correct race.

Comment: thanks so much for explaining it so well, i was really having trouble thinking of what to search to find other questions like mine, and thanks even more for going the extra mile and also showing me how to catch the exceptions!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to get `race.orc` if the user enters `orc`, and henceforth.

You're on the right track, you just need to input the String from the user, like

```
String s = inputRace.next();
player player1 = new player(race.valueOf(s), profession.ranger);
```